# AssetsManager in Typeface

Tags: android

Typeface.createFromAsset(AssetManager mgr,String path);
how to use this?

```
AssetManager mgr;
tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mgr, font);
TextView txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
txtName.setText(novena.getName());
txtName.setTypeface(tf);
```

how to initialize mgr?

you can use 
tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), font);

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
AssetManager mgr;
...
mgr = getAssets();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
//If you are inside of an ACtivity, and NOT inside of an inner class
AssetManager mgr = getAssets();
```